# How can I calculate point's coordinates based on bounding box and tap click on phone screen?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, android

E.g. I have bounding box `[94818.24, 116189.125] [94818.914, 116189.8]` and point's coordinate on my screen `[695, 1082]`.
So how can I get a coordinate in CRS=EPSG:99781

Comment: What are the coordinates of the bounding box on the screen?

Comment: 99781 doesn't exist in the EPSG registry either. So what coordinate reference system do you really want to use?